Is it possible to reverse construct a first-order homogeneous (no forcing term) difference equation from its general solution?
The solution to $y' = a(t)y$ is $y = Ce^{\int a(t)dt}$.  If I start with a general solution to this ODE such as $y = Ct$, then I can use algebra to find that $a(t) = \frac{1}{t}$, and reverse construct the ODE as $y' = \frac{1}{t}y$.  Of course, I am assuming that the form should be $y' = a(t)y$, and there may be ODEs of other forms with the same general solution.
I am having trouble doing an analogous trick with difference equations.  The only solution I can find to $x[n + 1] = b[n]x[n]$ is $x[n] = D\Pi_{i = 1}^{n - 1} b[i]$.  This is harder to deal with because it references the individual elements of $b$, even though technically $b$ is still a function of $n$ once the product over elements is resolved.  Is there a way I can solve this equation for $b[n]$ analogous to the differential equation solution?  What is the inverse operation of taking the product over elements in this way?
